# Java program for relational algebra

Tags: java

I'm working on a java program that perform basic relational algebra operations include UNION, INTERSECTION, DIFFERENCE and JOIN, on two tables (T1 and T2)

Union: the union of T1 and T2 results in all the records/tuples from both tables with no duplicates.

Difference: the difference of T1 and T2 results in all records in T1 that are not in T2.

Intersection: the intersection of T1 and T2 results in all the records/tuples from both tables that are the same.

Join: The join of T1 and T2 result in all records/tuples from both tables if there is a match on the given key.

This is what I come up with :

```
public class reading_file {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        int i = 0;
        int i2 = 0;
        String name1 = null;
        String name2 = null;
        File is1 =new File("T1.txt");
        File is2 =new File("T2.txt");
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(is1);
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(is2);
        sc1.nextLine(); 
        sc2.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("join"+"   "+"Union"+"   " + "intesection"+"   " + "T1 diff T2"+"   " + "T2 diff T1");
        System.out.println("ID" +" "+"Name"+" "+"ID" +" "+"Name"+"   " + "ID" +" "+ "Name"+"     " + "ID" +" "+ "Name"+"     " + "ID" +" "+ "Name");
        while (sc1.hasNext() && sc2.hasNext() && sc1.hasNextInt() && sc2.hasNextInt()) {

                i = sc1.nextInt();
                i2 = sc2.nextInt();
                name1 = sc1.next();
                name2 = sc2.next();
                if (i == i2){
                System.out.println(i +"   "+name1);

                }
                else  if (name1.equals(name2) && i == i2){
                 System.out.println("         "+name1 +"   "+i +"     "+ i +"    "+name1);
                 }
             else if (!name1.equals(name2) && i != i2) {
                 System.out.println("         "+name1 +"   "+ i +"                "+ name1 +"   "+ i);
                 System.out.println("         "+name2 +"   "+ i2+"                             "+ name2 +"   "+ i2);

             } 

        } 
        sc1.close();
        sc2.close();        
    }

}
```

and this my output :

```
join   Union   intersection   T1 diff T2   T2 diff T1
ID Name ID Name   ID Name     ID Name     ID Name
1   A
         Z   26                Z   26
         B   2                             B   2
3   C
```

As you can see the union and intersection do not display the correct answers.So my questions are:

How can I correct this ?
and Is this the easiest way to do this ?

Comment: Create a Tuple class. Implement equals() and hashCode() correctly. Create two Set<Tuple> (one for each file), and use the methods of Set to compute the union, the difference, the intersection, etc.

Comment: No this is not the easiest way to do this. But this is too braid to get proper answers. You need to break this down and ask a more specific question. Why are you concatenating a bunch of literal Strings?

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie then how would you implement this ?

Comment: Try breaking it down as I said. How about solving just the union part. What is an example input and what is the output you would expect? JB Nizet has some good suggestions in his comment, did you try those?

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie Working on it ! I think I will use sets. Thank you btw